# Appscript Pricing and Quota for fetching data from Bigquery to spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

**Background**

I am using App Script in google spreadsheet to fetch data from google bigquery.

**Query**

I wanted to know,whether google will charge, for using app script for big query service or the bytes processed by the app script while fetching data from bigquery to spreadsheet and is there a limit metrics for this app script.

Any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

You will be charged for the same price as just query run in Web UI. So it's $5 per TB. 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

App script work here is free. 
You can find detailed billing statistics here
https://console.cloud.google.com/billing

Answer (score 1):

Since the 'Apps script BigQuery service' uses the [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/) behind the scenes, the same restrictions, charges and limits apply.

As you can see in the table on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing), loading and retreiving data are free operations so no charge applies.

**Free operations:**

```
**Action**            **Examples**
Loading data          Loading data into BigQuery
Copying data          Copying an existing table
Exporting data        Exporting data from BigQuery
Metadata operations   List, get, patch, update and delete calls
```

source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing